# SSIS 2008 sql task returning a variable

Tags: ssis

I have a problem when trying to retrieve a value from a sql task and pass it to an integer variable. I configure the sql task with resultSet in a single row  and Result Name = "0" , Variable Name ="Myvar"
Here is the code I use in the sql statement:

```
select max(runid) from table
```

with this query, using the max function, my variable get always the default value.
However when using the code:

```
select runid from table
```

, my variable get the correct data.
Can you see what wrong is?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try adding an alias? "select max(runid) as runid from table". Shouldn't matter though, I created a test package and max() populated a variable just fine.

Comment: Glad it worked - I added it as an answer so if others search/have this same problem, they can easily see the solution.

Comment: If the answer below works, would you mind clicking the check mark to indicate the problem has been solved?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding an alias?

```
select max(runid) as runid from table
```